# Custom components can't access default NativeScript directives

Tags: nativescript

I've been using NativeScript for a while in some projects. One think I noticed is that "default" NativeScript directives, such as `nsRouterLink`, `tap` and some others does not work with components that I created.

The only times those directives works are when they are using with its default" components such as `GridLayout`, `Label`, etc.

I've created a small PlayGround project to demonstrate my issue: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=rZYQGP&v=3

I think I should import those directives into my custom components somehow, but I have no idea how.

Comment: If you have your custom component extend, for example, `GridLayout`, does it work?

Comment: @IanMacDonald i tried that and doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not as same as Web with NativeScript, you have to attach the events to the actual element and not on the custom selectors. An alternative is that you can emit an event on your custom component when actual element is tapped.

There is a [open feature request](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/1422) already.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert but I had same issue recently and could make workaround.

NativeScript's pure component should be registered appropriate
ly on Angular environment to work properly.

This can be done with `registerElement` from `nativescript-angular/element-registry`. 
By registering, the Angular Component should work like intended element.

Unfortunately, the property of the element can only be accessed with `HostBinding`

I have forked and applied workaround to PlayGround project you have provided: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=SCLxVk